# Swapping Reference Versions during Continuous Integration (CCNET)

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I'm leading a team of 4 building an application which is targeted at both 32 and 64 bit machines. One of the challenges we are facing is that when building (and deploying and unit-testing) on a 64-bit machine one of the 3rd-party DLLs we use needs to be the 64-bit version, when we run the test suite on a 32-bit machine it needs to be the 32-bit version.

Is there a way to manage the versions of those references in an automated fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to create a new configuration in each of your projects: one for 32-bit and one for 64-bit.  In each project, condition the reference to each third-party assembly on this configuration:

```
<Reference Include="ThirdPartyx86.dll" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug32'" />
<Reference Include="ThirdPartx64.dll" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug64'" />
```

Each configuration will have a name.  You pass that the configuration name from CCNet to MSBuild:

```
MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Debug32
MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Debug64
```

Comment: This worked perfectly in the POC project I put together tonight. I had the app using the same 3rd party component working flawlessly without modification both on my x64 development machine and the x86 server running CCNet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or use the $(Platform) property.
E.g. ($Platform ) == 'x86' or ($Platform ) == 'x64'

Comment: You would still need to have separate config I think (I don't think you can pass the platform to msbuild?). But these would just define which platform build against.

Comment: The multi-file option would have been my second choice had the previous suggestion not worked. Needing only to modify the available configurations from within VS is a big bonus.